# Приходит пустой POST запрос

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, scala, playframework

Собираю Json и отправляю так:

```
var obj = new Object();
        obj.id = currentID;
        obj.name = $('#name').val();
        obj.age = $('#age').val();
        console.log(obj);

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/edit",
           data: JSON.stringify(obj),
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (msg) {
               if (msg) {
                   alert(obj.name + obj.age + " was send");
               } else {
                   alert("Cannot send !");
               }
           }
       });
```

на сервер приходит None

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NoSuchElementException: None.get]]
```

Контроллер:

```
def edit = Action{ request =>
    val json = request.body.asJson.get
    Ok("ок")
  }
```

routes:

```
POST /edit                                          controllers.UserController.edit
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: Когда в Advanced REST вручную отправляю POST c JSON'ом, то контроллер отрабатывает. Отсюда вывод - я не правильно отправляю JSON или собираю. Но в материалах, которые просмотрел, в том числе на этом сайте, все делали так

Comment: `data: obj;` тоже пробовал, не получается все равно

Comment: во вкладке network видите, что запрос уходит?

Comment: Да, уходит. Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error. Вот FormData`{"id":1,"name":"Alex Mcqueen","age":"26"}:`

Comment: ну и смотри - 500 - ошибка на сервере.

Comment: @СергейПетрашко 500-я ошибка, потому, что на сервере `NoSuchElementException`, а `None` получается в этой части: `.asJson`. @СлаваИванов, покажите что у вас приходит в `request.body`

Comment: @СлаваИванов А вообще, придти на сервер кроме `json` может что угодно. Поэтому возьмите себе за правило никогда не писать `.get`(не только в такой ситуации, а вообще в какой угодно). Следует обмазывать такие места проверками.